# Convert this SQL to lambda for EF 4 Code first

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have this Sql statement

```
SELECT * FROM Game 
        INNER JOIN Series ON Series.Id = Game.SeriesId 
        INNER JOIN SeriesTeams ON SeriesTeams.SeriesId = Series.Id 
        INNER JOIN Team ON Team.Id = SeriesTeams.TeamId 
        INNER JOIN TeamPlayers ON TeamPlayers.TeamId = Team.Id 
        INNER JOIN Player ON Player.Id = TeamPlayers.PlayerId 
    WHERE AND Game.StartTime >= GETDATE() 
        AND Player.Id = 1
```

That I want to be converted into a lambda expression.

This is how it works.

A game can only be joined to 1 series, but a serie can of course have many games. A serie can have many teams and a team can join many series.
A player can play in many teams and a team has many players.

SeriesTeams and TeamPlayers are only the many-to-many tables created by EF to hold the references between series/teams and Teams/Players

Thanks in advance...

Edit: I use the EF 4 CTP5 and would like to have the answer as lambda functions, or in linq if that is easier...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, first of all, if you want to make sure that everything is eager-loaded when you run your query, you should add an explicit `Include`:

```
context.
Games.
Include(g => g.Series.Teams.Select(t => t.Players)).
Where(g => 
         g.StartTime >= DateTime.Now && 
         g.Series.Teams.Any(t => t.Players.Any(p => p.Id == 1))).
ToList();
```

However, as I mentioned in my comment, this won't produce the same results as your SQL query, since you don't filter out the players from the child collection.

EF 4.1 has some nifty [Applying filters when explicitly loading related entities](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx) features, but I couldn't get it to work for sub-sub-collections, so I think the closest you can get to your original query would be by projecting the results onto an anonymous object (or you can create a class for that if you need to pass this object around later on):

```
var query = context.
            Games.
            Where(g =>
                     g.StartTime >= DateTime.Now && 
                     g.Series.Teams.Any(t => t.Players.Any(p => p.Id == 1))).
            Select(g => new
                        {
                            Game = g,
                            Players = g.
                                      Series.
                                      Teams.
                                      SelectMany(t => t.
                                                      Players.
                                                      Where(p => p.Id == user.Id))
                        });
```

Then you can enumerate and inspect the results:

```
var gamesAndPlayersList = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Hi. I will try it out. I guess the SQL statement produced by EF isn't as "nice" as my orginal sql statement. One way could be to create a View that gives me exactly the information I want from the diffrent tables, and execute that instead, and then create this special entity to match that result. Wouldn't be as nice as doing the above, but could give me better performance against the database. I have to do some perfomance test to deciede if it's worth the extra work.

Answer (score 1):

I did found the solution.

```
IList<Domain.Model.Games> commingGames = this.Games
 .Where(a => a.StartTime >= DateTime.Now && a.Series.Teams.Any(t => t.Players.Any(p => p.Id == user.Id))).ToList();
```

If somebody has a better solution then I am all ears..

Comment: This won't give the same results as your SQL query, though. The difference is that the SQL query returns only players with `Id == 1`, while your LINQ query will return a list of games for player 1, but along with ALL the players in the same team as player 1 (the child collection is not filtered). Is this the output you are actually looking for? Furthermore, without lazyloading you won't even be able to access any navigational properties (only the `Games` will be loaded from the DB). What version of EF are you using?

Comment: Yes, I see it's EF4 CTP5 - sorry I did not re-read your question and see the edit before posting my comment. Any reason for not switching to EF4.1, btw?

Comment: Sorry! I actually use EF4.1 the EF4 CTP5 must be of old habbit :). Regarding that I get all players in the team as player 1. How should I change the lambda expression to only show the games for player 1?